# Cannot alter schema name in MYSQL 5.5 w/ MYSQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, database, schema, mysql-workbench

Why I cannot alter my schema name from the MYSQL Workbench? Am i missing something? :(

As you can the name is dissabled

[image]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is no RENAME available for schema names.  You will have to export the schema, then import with a new database name.

This is a limitation of the MySQL server itself.

Answer (score 11):

Actually, you can rename database name very easily,

1. go to the top menu -> Database -> reverse engineering, select your database and keep go further until you get the er diagram of your database,
2. after the there is an area called Catalog Area under that you can see your database name, right click on that and select edit schema. and change your database name
3. now again go to the top menu -> database -> forward engineering and completed the database engineering using the wizard.

Comment: This is not renaming. This just creates another schema with the new name. However the steps mentioned are helpful.

Comment: Not _the_ solution, but _a_ step towards a solution. Doesn't transfer the data but other than that it's pretty neat. Cheers

Answer (score 7):

I can't imagine that anyone is still using version 5.5, but here is the procedure I followed in version 8. If you do have an older/newer version this may still work.

1. Connect to the database.
2. Open the Database menu and choose Migration Wizard.
3. Start Migration.
4. Both source and target will be the current MySQL server.
5. Select the schema you want to rename.
6. For Source Objects make sure all the tables are selected.
7. Click Next and you will see a message that the source and target are the same.
8. Now you should see a "Manual Editing" step.
9. Under the Target Object column, click on the database name and change it.
10. Now you can click next all the way through.
11. Once finished you will have a newly renamed schema.

> Currently my database has no indexes, stored procedures, etc. You will
>   want to confirm all related objects are migrated as well before
>   dropping the old database.

Comment: Got an error at the second last step (transfer data)

Answer (score 1):

Gavin is right, but if your server have phpMyAdmin, you can use it to rename your database (schema):

1. Go to your phpMyAdmin URL. Default is http://yourdomain.com/phpMyAdmin/
2. If prompted, enter your database username and password.
3. Click on "Operations" tab.
4. Under "Rename database to:" write your new database name.
5. Click "Go" button.
6. If prompted, click "OK".
7. After some seconds, depending on your database content, you will have your database renamed.

What phpMyAdmin is actually doing is create a new database with your new name, import the content from your current database and delete your current database.